# C++ typename as variable

Tags: c++, variables, types, typename

Suppose I have a template class MyClass. 
Is it possible to store the type of the template as an variable of the class? If so how? I'm curious if it's possible to do something like this.

```
Template <typename T> class MyClass;
Template <typename T> class AnotherClass;

MyClass<int> myClassInstance;
AnotherClass<oneInstance.functionThatReturnsTheStoredTypeFromAnInstanceVariableOfMyClass()> anotherClassInstance;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to compile and test it? did it work?

Comment: Are you trying to get `AnotherClass<MyClass<int>>`, or `AnotherClass<int>` ?

Comment: @NirMH, I would have tried to compile it if I would have known how to store the type passed in to the template as a variable in the instance of the class, which looks like it's not exactly possible.

Comment: @Useless, I was just curious if it's possible to store the type as an instance variable and then use the value of that instance variable to pass on to another class template as a type or create other variables using it, much like the Class type in Objective-C where you can do stuff like, Class someClass = [someObject class]; id newInstanceOfSomeClass = [[someClass alloc] init]; In case you are an Obj-C programmer, my example is flawed, doesn't exactly work for CoreFoundation bridged stuff for ex, NSString *instance... [instance class] returns NSCFString;

Comment: The typedef mechanism used by @DeadMG is what you want then (and this technique is used a lot in the STL) ... it just isn't _called_ an instance variable, because it doesn't vary, and is really a property of the type rather than the instance.

Comment: @thealch3m1st: Your Obj-C example is rather different from what you asked in the original question. In the Obj-C example the static type of newInstance is id, not MyClass*, and definitely not an instance of a different class template with a parameter derived from the type of someObject. What you did in ObjC can be done in C++ (you pass someObject to a function template taking a T*, in that function create a new T(), cast it to void* and return), and what you originally asked for cannot be done in ObjC either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They can be static variables, you can nest typedefs.

```
template<typename T> class MyClass {
public:
    typedef T type;
};
AnotherClass<MyClass<double>::type> anotherClassInstance;
```

However, accessing a member variable like you posted is impossible in C++.

Comment: +1, you need to edit your code; it should be `class/struct MyClass`.

Comment: I wouldn't call the name of a nested type a variable.

Comment: Oh darn it. Is there any way to create something like the Class type in Objective-C ?

Comment: @Luc, the answer is correct, if you go with what OP wants. We don't have to capture every word of the question especially when the asker is novice. Here OP may have meant variable as type. DeadMG, you need to put `type` in `public` access.

Comment: @iammilind My comment has nothing to do with the OP, I'm only commenting on this particular answer. Do you call `i` in `const int i = 42;` a variable? Do you call `f` in `void f();` a variable? Issues of terminology may not be fun but are important.

Comment: @thealc3m1st: No, you cannot create or deal with types at run-time in C++ in any way, except within the bounds provided by RTTI (typeid() and dynamic_cast) C++ does provide exceptionally powerful (for an imperative/OO language) functionality for manipulating them at compile-time, but little at run-time.